# can't run migrate:install in laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

i have laravel 5 and it works fine on browser.After then for making table in database, firstly i have create directory i.e /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel, then run php artisan migrate:install command but i have got message shown below. How to solve this problem.

cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/lovey

/opt/lampp/htdocs/lovey$ php artisan migrate:install

---

- Application In Production!     *

  ---

  Do you really wish to run this command? [y/N] (yes/no) [no]:

  > 

HERE IS MY database.php file.
my database name is laravel.

return
 [
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

],



'migrations' => 'migrations',



'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

];

Comment: Could you please share your .env ? I think there might be a problem in your enviroment options.

Comment: actually i have installed laravel5 in ubuntu 12.04, so there is no .env file in my laravel folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your .env is required for laravel to run properly. The .env file stores your enviroment configuration, your database configuration included.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation#environment-configuration

Example of .env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=J9dFWi5QPq2aIuAX9XAfnuOoKVmNsFHs

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

If you create your laravel project with composer:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

A .env will be created. If you have created any other way .env may not have been created, but you will have a file named .env.example, you can copy/rename the file to .env and your laravel instalation should work fine.

Also if your application is in production you should change your APP_* parameters.